# Convert color name string to rgb value in Arduino

Tags: arduino, rgb, lookup-tables, arduino-c++

I'm doing a project with Arduino ESP8266-1 and a RGB LED strip. The ESP sends strings to the Arduino via serial with the name of the colors to be set (example: "red", "yellow", "purple") and I need to convert that string into an RGB value (eg. (255, 100, 255)).

How can I do this?

I've tried to create a list of array with values like this:

```cpp
int red = {255, 0, 0};
```

and next in the loop:

```cpp
String com = "red";
if (com == "red") {
  colorLed = red;
}
```

but with more colors, it's not the best way. What would be a better way?

Comment: is there any good reason why you send the colorname instead of the rgb touple?

Comment: because the esp is connected to google assistant and google on my command send me string like: "{"deviceId":"xxx","action":"action.devices.commands.ColorAbsolute","value":{"color":blue}}"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach to your problem would be to convert from HEX to RGB (there are quite plenty of C++ samples of code to do that).

You could declare each *"color"* as their HEX equivalent and use some easy byte converter to convert them to RGB.

Here for example a sample HEX to RGB converter:

```
byte red, green, blue;
unsigned long rgb = B787B7;

red = rgb >> 16

green = (rgb & 0x00ff00) >> 8;

blue = (rgb & 0x0000ff);

rgb = 0;

rgb |= red << 16;
rgb |= blue << 8;
rgb |= green;
```

Comment: it is `0xB787B7` not `B787B7` , your do not answer the question. also I understand that you suggest to send that rgb value over the serial connection and then split it into r, g, and b. Why would you send a 4 byte number if you could simply send the 3 r g b bytes? that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is clever to send string representations instead of rgb touples but if you insist on doing so you can use a hash map for example.

[Example using Wiring](http://wiring.org.co/reference/libraries/HashMap/HashMap_CreateHashMap_.html):

```
#include <HashMap.h>
//create hashMap that pairs char* to int and can hold 3 pairs
CreateHashMap(hashMap, char*, int, 3); 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //add and store keys and values
  hashMap["newKey"] = 12;
  hashMap["otherKey"] = 13;

  //check if overflow (there should not be any danger yet)
  Serial.print("Will the hashMap overflow now [after 2 assigns] ?: ");
  Serial.println(hashMap.willOverflow());

  hashMap["lastKey"] = 14;

  //check if overflow (this should be true, as we have added 3 of 3 pairs)
  Serial.print("Will the hashMap overflow now [after 3 assigns] ?: ");
  Serial.println(hashMap.willOverflow());

  //it will overflow, but this won't affect the code.
  hashMap["test"] = 15;

  //change the value of newKey
  Serial.print("The old value of newKey: ");
  Serial.println(hashMap["newKey"]);

  hashMap["newKey"]++;

  Serial.print("The new value of newKey (after hashMap['newKey']++): ");
  Serial.println(hashMap["newKey"]);

  //remove a key from the hashMap
  hashMap.remove("otherKey");

  //this should work as there is now an availabel spot in the hashMap
  hashMap["test"] = 15;

  printHashMap();
}

void loop() {
}

void printHashMap() 
{
  for (int i=0; i<hashMap.size(); i++) 
  {
    Serial.print("Key: ");
    Serial.print(hashMap.keyAt(i));
    Serial.print(" Value: ");
    Serial.println(hashMap.valueAt(i));
  }
}
```